# I want to install gcc-g++ 3.3x in windows 10 (Cygwin)

Tags: c, gcc, g++, cygwin, win64

I have to use compile a program using ./configure in Cygwin.But when I run the command it is showing that Need gcc version of gcc 3.3.x. I checked in cygwin it only has the newer versions. Is there any way that i can install older versions in cygwin or mingw??

Comment: Usually you should be able to use a newer gcc version. You may need to disable some warnings, but other than that things should work.

Comment: I agree with @icebp . Adjusting the program to accept a gcc > 3.3.x is much more easy than backporting a very old compiler. Is the program available on the web ?